# How to change background color in diffuse color render pass?

Tags: render-passes

[image]

I looked around and seems like its not possible according to another post. As a workaround, i'm using a bunch of white images to act as the background color change. Any way to change the black color itself or a better workaround?

Comment: For rendering? The diffuse pass is a light pass and usually for compositing purposes so to me it makes sense that it is pure black. What's the reason you'd like to change this?

Comment: to see the flat color with black outline in the render, but cant see the black outline with the black background

Comment: I might use depth, cryptomatte, or Film->Transparent to filter out the background.

Comment: Agree with @ZargulTheWizard Remove your planes, go to *Render Properties > Film*,  enable *Transparent* and choose any image format supporting an alpha channel eg. png + alpha or ideally OpenEXR.